# How to provision large scale of IoT devices with multitenancy as a major concern in Azure IoT?

Tags: azure, provisioning

I am using Azure sphere device with Azure device provisioning service (DPS) to connect to IoT hub.

I know DPS is a good way to handle provisioning in multitenancy but, let's say I have 1000 Azure sphere devices (or any other IoT devices) with the use of Azure IoT SDK I can develop device application which will have my DPS service configuration code. Now if I develop this application on single device and deploy it on OTA for all other 999 device will it connect to the IoT hub which is configured in DPS cloud portal?

Would this be a good approach to develop application for multitenant scenario?
So at the end if I have 5 tenants I will develop 5 seperate application with same DPS code configured and it will connect to IoT hub by communicating with DPS, is it right?

if not what am I missing here? any suggestions, documentation would be helpful.